# YEOMAN run multiple sub generators in one function

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have an angular based generator with three sub generators for controller directive and service. I want to run one function that takes the NAME variable/input and runs all three of these at the same time instead of having to run each one separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman offers `composeWith()` ([docs](http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html)) which you can use to invoke other (sub)generators.

```js
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
    this.argument('theName', {
      type: String,
      required: true
    });
  },

  initializing: function() {
    this.composeWith('my-generator:mysubgen1', { args: [this.theName] });
    this.composeWith('my-generator:mysubgen2', { args: [this.theName] });
  }
});
```

In the example above I assume your generator is named `my-generator` and has two subgenerators (`mysubgen1` and `mysubgen2`).

The code above would go into a third subgenerator, e.g. `doall`. If you call `$ yo my-generator:doall foobar` it would now run both of the composed sub-generators, passing `foobar` as first argument.

Comment: thank you this is spot on surprised I missed this in the documentation.